# Output the smallest increasing sequence where each term is coprime to preceding 3 terms

Tags: code-golf, number, sequence, integer

This sequence is defined as

- Starts with 1, 2, 3
- The next element of the sequence is the first number greater than the previous three that is co-prime with each of the previous *3* elements in the sequence.

  - In other words, if the previous 3 elements are `a`, `b`, `c`, then the next is the first integer `n>c` such that `gcd(a,n)=gcd(b,n)=gcd(c,n)=1`.

This sequence on OEIS: [OEIS](https://oeis.org/A062062)

All elements below 100:

```py
1,2,3,5,7,8,9,11,13,14,15,17,19,22,23,25,27,28,29,31,
33,34,35,37,39,41,43,44,45,47,49,52,53,55,57,58,59,61,
63,64,65,67,69,71,73,74,75,77,79,82,83,85,87,88,89,
91,93,94,95,97,99,
```

You can either:

- Take a number as input, then output the Nth element in the sequence. Either 0 or 1 based is fine.
- Take a number as input, then output the first N elements in this sequence.
- Take no input, output the sequence infinitely.

[Inspired by a discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/64204669#64204669)

Comment: Note: it’s recommended to post challenges in the sandbox first, but it’s still quite good.

Comment: @TheEmptyStringPhotographer The sequel is in the sandbox but this one is so straightforward I felt it wasn't really necessary to go through the sandbox process

Comment: Does N count the initial 1,2,3 seed?  Should f(1) be 1 or 5?  I think you’ll get shorter solutions if f(N) returned the first N+3 elements or the N+3rd.  Or if you only care about N>3.

Comment: @doug You can set the seed to 1,1,1 and get the same behavior you suggest without giving different output than the example

Comment: Okay, I’ll take that to mean you’re not fussy about the low values of N.  Being pedantic, the example doesn’t indicate what invocation should generate that output.

Answer (score 12):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>78</s> 77 bytes

*-1 byte thanks to @Bubbler!*

Prints the 0-indexed `n`-th term of the sequence. Who needs `gcd` anyway?

```python
lambda n:sum((v+(t+b''+v+t)*n)[:n])+1
v=b''*3
t=(b''+v[1:]+v[6:])*3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcyxCsMgFEBRtJn8Cjff00UJdBD8ktRBadMGmpdgrdCvty53OtzzV18HzX0Nt/5Oe74nSf7z3QGagWqymhibuDLNVNSEi6eIxokWsmKMc6VnUQNkdRlkcT6OXn1EPY5HkSQ3kiXR8wHOWoteyLNsVGEFQux/)

If we look at the differences between each term in the sequence, they become periodic after the 7th term, repeating every 125th term. The periodic string is:

```python
22112231221122112222112231221122112222112231221122112222112241142112211221122312211221122221122312211221122221122312211221122
```

The code simply attempts to construct this periodic string, plus the non-periodic bit at the beginning. It helps that the string naturally contains a lot of repetition, making compression relatively short.

By the way, the unprintables in ASCII are `41142`, `1122`, and `3` in order of appearance.

Comment: `t=(b'\x03'+v[1:]+v[6:])*3` is one byte shorter. (literal ascii 3 is not allowed in comments)

Answer (score 7):

## [Python](https://www.python.org), <s>81</s> 79 bytes

```python
from math import*
*a,d=1,
while 1:a+=[d][:gcd(prod(a[-3:]),d)<2!=print(d)];d+=1
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72soLIkIz9vwYKlpSVpuhY3_dOK8nMVchNLMhQycwvyi0q0uLQSdVJsDXW4yjMyc1IVDK0StW2jU2KjrdKTUzQKivJTNBKjdY2tYjV1UjRtjBRtC4oy80o0UjRjrVO0bQ0hxkJNh9kCAA) Prints the sequence indefinitely.

Comment: That's a nifty trick for conditionally appending and printing a value!

Answer (score 6):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <sup><s>43</s></sup> 41 bytes

```
{{{y+/1<y(|!\)/x,y}[x*y*z]/z}\[x-3].1+!3}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwVjr1uwkAQBvt7igBS+Jtg9vbWe2tFCq2fAaMkDelTRBgCzx6n+bqZ+c7d7XYbt428jqvf2bBuLoz342Uzbq6n5nofjpcXPe1kO9N7Sk0SMorhVAIRRJGCGOJIkDNZyUZ2ciUHKiRVtKCGOhoUoSilUIzilMAyNmkNc6xiQTthrdIWWqN12sAFV7zgU9/xoGaqUo06/anUIIUQShTCCCciDSl1fbejkff+8PxY9W8s580wzNfL1WzRd/vu4/P76+dJ1in1j/Nh0af/+QMJcz05)

-2 thanks to ovs. The original version had `(|!\|!\)/` for the GCD (because `(|!\)` alternates between `0,gcd` and `gcd,0` in the end). ovs suggested `y(|!\)/` which iterates exactly `y` times, which is valid because:

- at each iteration, `x,y` becomes `y%x,x`, which strictly reduces the minimum of the two until one becomes 0 (except at the first iteration, because `x > y` at that point); the minimum is reduced at least `y-1` times
- the above leaves the possibility that the minimum is reduced by 1 `y-1` times in a row, but it is impossible: after one reduction, the pair becomes `y-1,y`, and after one more, `1,y-1`, which is a reduction of more than 1 if `y >= 4`.

Comment: Nifty observation

Comment: Instead of doing the double-step for converging, I think `y(|!\)/` should be fine

Comment: [same length](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwVjrFSAkEQRPP9CoEqAXm6zM7Ozc5plab3DRylJpgbWEchfLtn0lG/fn3qLxOX8y7Ly3nzuxi3eeJ8PTzkR11Nxyy7fZ6u+fC82B9TykkoKIbTCEQQRSpiiCNBKRSlGMUpjRKokFTRihrqaFCFqtRKNapTAyvYPGuYYw0LuhnrlK7SGZ3TBS644hWf/Y4HrdCUZrT5T6MFKYRQohJGOBFpTGnon8jyPrzd3zbDK+tlHsfldr1ZrIZ+3398fn/93Ml27t1Ob6sh/ccfbq47og==) without recurrence, and technically [-2](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m700Oz4vPW_BgqWlJWm6FjfVqyt0qiu19Q1tKjVqFGM09St0KmujtfR1jZUrYvUNtRViDPQravUNIcqhumC6AQ) by printing indefinitely, but that one just feels wrong.

Answer (score 5):

## [K (ngn/k)](https://codeberg.org/ngn/k), <sup>59</sup> 52 bytes

```
{{{~1=(*|(*:)(|!\)/)y,x}[x*y*z](1+)/z+1}\[x-3].1+!3}
```

[Try it online!](https://ngn.codeberg.page/k#eJwNjjtOw0AQQPs9BUkkYjuPmNnZ8exYQqT1GXAENKGnQPmfnRzgfQ7j5XK5y1vTXZtubJvrYm779sTx9nHsTt1538im7c8buc0fxxfdb2Wz0FtKfRIyiuFUAhFEkYIY4kiQM1nJRnZyJQcqJFW0oIY6GhShKKVQjOKUwDL20BrmWMWC4YENylAYjMEZAhdc8YI/+o4HNVOVatTHT6UGKYRQohBGOBFpTmmcxi29fE6753szvbNe9vO8bNfNYjWNr+PX9+/P35O0KU33w241pX9XLT4P)

-7 : peeking at @ovs’s solution suggested obvious golf

Answer (score 5):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), <s>16</s> <s>14</s> <s>13</s> 12 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
λ∞+Dλ3.£P¿Ïн
```

-1 byte thanks to *@ovs*.

Outputs the infinite sequence.

[Try it online.](https://tio.run/##AR4A4f9vc2FiaWX//8674oieK0TOuzMuwqNQwr/Dj9C9//8)

**Explanation:**

```python
λ         # Start a recursive environment,
          # to output the infinite sequence
          # (which is output implicitly at the end)
          # Implicitly starting with a(0)=1
          # Where every following a(n) is calculated as:
          #  (implicitly push a(n-1))
 ∞        #  Push an infinite positive list: [1,2,3,...]
  +       #  Add the a(n-1) to each: [a(n-1)+1,a(n-1)+2,a(n-1)+3,...]
 D        #  Duplicate this infinite list
  λ       #  Push a list of all items thus far: [a(0),a(1),...,a(n-1)]
   3.£    #  Pop and only leave (up to†) the last three items: [a(n-3),a(n-2),a(n-1)]
      P   #  Take the product of this triplet: a(n-3)*a(n-2)*a(n-1)
       ¿  #  Check the gcd (Greatest Common Divisor) of this product with each value `v`
          #  in the infinite (duplicated) list: gcd(v,a(n-3)*a(n-2)*a(n-1))
  Ï       #  †† Pop both lists, and only leave the values at the truthy††† positions
   н      #  Pop and push the first remaining item of this infinite list
```

Footnotes:

- †: In the first two iterations, `λ` won't contain three items yet, so will be `[1]` or `[1,"2"]` respectively. This won't affect the output though, since it'll calculate \$2\$ based on just \$[a(0)=1]\$ and calculate \$3\$ based on \$[a(0)=1,a(1)=2]\$.
- ††: The outputs are strings (except for the first implicit item) because of the `Ï` builtin. Not sure why it does that tbh. (You could add a `ï` to the footer if you prefer actual integer outputs: [Try it online](https://tio.run/##ASAA3/9vc2FiaWX//8674oieK0TOuzMuwqNQwr/Dj9C9/8Ov/w).)
- †††: Only `1` is truthy in 05AB1E, so only the items at which `gcd(v,a(n-3)*a(n-2)*a(n-1))==1` will be kept with `Ï`.

Comment: If you take the product of the last three items before computing the *gcd*, you can get rid of the `δ`

Answer (score 3):

-10 from ovs/emanresu A

-5 from Arnauld

-3 from dingledooper

## [JavaScript (V8)](https://v8.dev/), 64 bytes

```javascript
for(A=B=C=D=j=1;;)A*B*C%j|D%j--||(j||print((A=B,B=C,C=D)),j=++D)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SMPR1snW2dbFNsvW0Npa01HLSctZNavGRTVLV7emRiOrpqagKDOvRAOkTgeoUgeoVlNTJ8tWW9tF8/9/AA)

Comment: [79](https://tio.run/##DcTBCoMwDADQrxkkmoHuJHZR2uYvxEMqrNSDShV/v@4d3qq3nktOx/W@u1J@ewbLjj0LtyYyKAXkIYwRAukrYK@mrgUj2MpVngS/n3Gy5MjPPP0noSOn7QLBuW9KeQA) with a trick from ovs's python answer

Comment: [74](https://tio.run/##FcsxDoAgDADA15i0Wgc3oylG4CPFRIKDGjRM/B3x9jskybPFcL99GkvZrwgrazZseZg9g5BDVm7x4Egah5PMXWfRw9rq1pBFNeR8x3C@8EeqlWpGLOUD)

Comment: [64 bytes](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNEts/j/Py2/SMPR1snW2dbFNsvW0Npa01HLSctZNavGRTVLV7emRiOrpqagKDOvRAOkTgeoUgeoVlNTJ8vWRVtb8/9/AA)

Answer (score 3):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 40 bytes

```
{1&(]],_3&{.>:@]^:(3<1#.+./)^:_{:)&1 2 3
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##NdA7SwNBGIXhPr/iI8ImSybj3G8YEQQrK/tNCnExNoLa7Y9f3xEspnnOYXbOfqxbvZvl1GQnSow0zlHL48vz07rYYT9N6uKHRd@3h@nc9v7O3uiDvh3P7bK0cbDixK/jZr5@ff@kIictVolT4pVEJVlJUVKVWNRiNnAILInFHVWHO8xhjrrDPX2Pe/qezJN5POABD3jAAx7wyD2xfxOLWOSeiCf6CU/0E1kiS3jGM57x3B@KZ7xwT8ELVvrruafglX7FK/1KVslq32X6MNOXmT7N9G2mjzN/q/1m8/b6/in//@fYZN4e5KpTWX8B)

0 indexed, returns the selected element, though it generates all up to that element under the hood.

Answer (score 3):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org), <s>83</s> 71 bytes

```r
a=3:1
repeat if(all(prod(a[1:3])%%2:a|(T=T+1)%%2:a))show((a=c(T,a))[4])
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=m72waMGCpaUlaboWN90TbY2tDLmKUgtSE0sUMtM0EnNyNAqK8lM0EqMNrYxjNVVVjawSazRCbEO0DSEcTc3ijPxyDY1E22SNEB0gN9okVhNiHNRUmOkA)

Answer (score 3):

## [Pyth](https://github.com/isaacg1/pyth), 18 bytes

```
#eaYf!-iT>3Y1he|Y0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsyfj/Xzk1MTJNUTczxM440jAjtSbS4P9/AA)

Outputs terms of the sequence indefinitely.

#### Explanation

```
                      # implicitly assign Y = []
#                     # repeat until error
               |Y0    #   short circuiting Y or 0
              e       #   last element of
             h        #   plus 1
    f                 #   counting up from this number, find the first element which satisfies lambda T
         >3Y          #     last three elements of Y
       iT             #     map to gcd with T
      -     1         #     remove 1 from this list
     !                #     True if list is empty
  aY                  #   append to Y
 e                    #   print the last element of Y
```

Answer (score 3):

## [Julia](https://julialang.org), <s>84</s> 79 bytes

```
~n=(i=A=1;while length(A)<n;if max(gcd.(last(A,3),i+=1)...)<2;A=[A;i]end;end;A)
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NZAxbsJAEEV7n8KlrfxYmp3dnR0ZS_EJcgBEYcECGzkWwkZQcZE0NBwqF0kdR4HiF6PR_zPvf90_Tn3qbrf7adq-hu_369AUqWkbqs_71Me8j8Nu2hdtuRjqtM0_u0uxW2-qou_GqWjBJdJLQ2VVVeXC1G2zbOu0isOm_lNbPmJ_umE8x2Pe5FdPWbwc4nqKm3lcEgwYDoIABRGIQRbkQAJSGAPDMA5GYAKMggkZM9iCHVjACkuwDGthHazAKpyBm2MdnMAFOIWfbZ7hLbyDF3iFEIQhFjLfF4giGARGcAjzPwFBkSlBGWqhDipQxSp768YxHqf8SdXkT6TscEzDVPwvHvTPcn8B)

Given \$n\$, returns \$[a_1, a_2, \ldots, a_n]\$.

The function `last(A,3)` works gracefully for vectors with less than 3 values.
Substituting `A=[A;i]` for `push!(A,i)` saves 3 bytes.
Incrementing `i` inside a function call saves 2 bytes.

- -4 bytes thanks to MarcMush: replace `i=1;A=[1]` with `i=A=1`
- -1 byte thanks to MarcMush: remove unecessary semicolon

Comment: -5 bytes with A=1 and removing a ; [ATO](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NZAxbsJAEEV7n8KlrfxYmp3dnR0ZS_EJcgBEYcECGzkWwkZQcZE0NBwqF0kdR4HiF6PR_zPvf90_Tn3qbrf7adq-hu_369AUqWkbqs_71Me8j8Nu2hdtuRjqtM0_u0uxW2-qou_GqWjBJdJLQ2VVVeXC1G2zbOu0isOm_lNbPmJ_umE8x2Pe5FdPWbwc4nqKm3lcEgwYDoIABRGIQRbkQAJSGAPDMA5GYAKMggkZM9iCHVjACkuwDGthHazAKpyBm2MdnMAFOIWfbZ7hLbyDF3iFEIQhFjLfF4giGARGcAjzPwFBkSlBGWqhDipQxSp768YxHqf8SdXkT6TscEzDVPwvHvTPcn8B)

Answer (score 2):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), 36 bytes

```
ＦＮ«≔⊕↨υ⁰θＷ¬⬤…²⊕θ∨﹪θλ﹪Π…⮌υ³λ≦⊕θ⊞υθ»Ｉυ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ZU47DsIwDJ3pKTI6UpD4jEzAxECpeoMQDKnkJm0@RQhx9pBIHZDwYj37/ZSWTllJKd2tY3AyQwx17K/ogHP2rhZ777uHyQ/lsEcT8AYH6RGiYCvOBRv5rlo8dUfIoLYB9kTQSvNA2Aj2qxoL@@LgbG@RLIyCUT7MqHF5qwDHlyI8ajtAixO6kpNJ2yIlXoad5fBfaa7RRK9LsQI@VeM6kx2lD9mE71Jar9Jyoi8) Link is to verbose version of code. Outputs the first `n` numbers. Explanation:

```
ＦＮ«
```

Repeat `n` times.

```
≔⊕↨υ⁰θ
```

Start with `1` more than the previous number, or `1` if there were no previous numbers.

```
Ｗ¬⬤…²⊕θ∨﹪θλ﹪Π…⮌υ³λ
```

While a common factor between the candidate number and the product of the last three numbers can be found...

```
≦⊕θ
```

... increment the candidate number.

```
⊞υθ
```

Add the next element to the list.

```
»Ｉυ
```

Output the found elements.

Answer (score 2):

## [Arturo](https://arturo-lang.io), 69 bytes

```arturo
a:@0..3i:5whileø[drop'a 1print a\0while->1<>gcd@[i∏a]->i:i+1'a++i]
```

[Try it!](http://arturo-lang.io/playground?pDtU4O) (Modified to print the first `n` elements so the playground can actually show the output.)

Prints the sequence indefinitely.

```
    a:@0..3             ; assign [0 1 2 3] to a
    i:5                 ; assign 5 to i
    whileø[             ; start infinite loop
        drop'a 1        ; delete the first element in a
        print a\0       ; print the (new) first element in a
        while->1<>      ; while 1 is not equal to...
        gcd@[i∏a]->     ; ...the gcd of i and the product of a
            i:i+1       ; increment i (without mutation)
        'a++i           ; append i to a
    ]                   ; end loop
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Vyxal](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyxal), 118 [bits<sup>v2</sup>](https://github.com/Vyxal/Vyncode/blob/main/README.md), 14.75 bytes

```
W£λ¥nġΠṅ;+)T⁺⌐Ḟ
```

[Try it Online!](https://vyxal.pythonanywhere.com/?v=2#WyI1PSIsIiIsIlfCo867wqVuxKHOoOG5hTsrKVTigbrijJDhuJ4iLCIiLCIiXQ==)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 34 bytes

```
($1 2 3,3((]+3<1#.+.)^:_{:)\])^:_~
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=LY89TsNAFIT7nGKVIGIrny3evl2_fVagQaKiok6gQFiIhsJQIXERGlNwCE6CuA2OQjGaKUbz8_H5NH0v27Aewnkf1oSz0M9o2nB5c3319foyNOV3WZ1IiEHRqtpvdCurdtPWt_3dW1_v9gfx_u_8qRfjIUiIKBmj4IggiiQkI4Y4MRKVmIlGLERHBZ0LEppRQ50kJCUlUiYZycmRPKdmspEL2emETukSXaYzOscEUyxhc7thTokUpWTKvKZQHBdc8YRn3HBfPNw_PochrMajqra7sQ5NH4bT9iKsduPx3jQd-Q8)

Returns first n terms. Very inefficient because it computes the next term for every 3-window at every iteration.

```
($1 2 3,3((]+3<1#.+.)^:_{:)\])^:_~
(                            )^:_~  repeat (...) on n until it converges,
                                    also giving n as the fixed left arg
                               (after 1 iteration, the value is always a
                                length-n array starting with 1 2 3)
 $1 2 3,3(                )\]  compute the next term for every 3-window,
                               prepend 1 2 3 and make it length n
          (]+3<1#.+.)^:_{:  compute the next term for a window:
          (         )^:_{:  iterate from the 3rd number until convergence:
                  +.        gcd with the 3 preceding terms
           ]+3<1#.          if the sum is >3, increment
```

## [J](https://www.jsoftware.com), 34 bytes

```
0{(]}.,](]+3<1#.+.)^:_{:)^:[&1 2 3
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=PY89TgNRDIT7nOIpkfKjfFnFz8_r5xXQIFFR0aINBSICGopAFXESmlBwCE6CuA2LgijG1lijGc_b--Phc9yk2TaddmlGWqduwKpJ51eXFx8vz9tV_R6v9_P-taGf90s9kUmzbBab7mbfDfN6Kikn_VN-LUa7XyMhoxhOJRBBFCmIIY4EOZOVbGQnV3KggipaUEMdDYpQlFIoRnFKYBkbXA1zrGJBK7RKW2iN1mkDF1zxgg_pjgc1U5Vq1OGbSg1CCCUKYYQTMbq7vX9K2-lZemgmuyPbpVX3fzrWOxyO-wc)

Returns the nth term, 0-indexed. Maintains the next 3 terms in a loop.

```
0{(]}.,](]+3<1#.+.)^:_{:)^:[&1 2 3
0{(                     )^:[&1 2 3  starting from 1 2 3, iterate n times
                                    and extract the first number
       ](]+3<1#.+.)^:_{:            compute the next term
    }.,                             prepend previous two terms
   ]                                ignore n in this function
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org), 73 bytes

```haskell
h n|n<4=n
h n=head[x|x<-[h$n-1..],all(\d->gcd d x==1)[h$n-1,h$n-2,h$n-3]]
```

[Attempt This Online!](https://ato.pxeger.com/run?1=NVAxasNAECStirxhCxc2jEz29k53C1b6vCCFokJEciQkC2MrYIJ_ksZNyJuS1-RskWYYGGaYmc_vtjr2zTBcLl_v0zYNP08tjedxY_MxiSxvm6ouTufTJi3axZjyel2iGoblS50-vr3WVNMpz3k1i7iiuaGU5Rz4e3e_7Q7HiXIqEiKGgcDBI0DBDBawBTuwByuMgREYB-NhAoxCGNEnArEQB_EQhWVYgbWwDtbDKpyBi8EOzsMFOEV2M2aCzCJzyDwyhWd4gbfwsYOHVwSDIAgOIXYKCHp1KUMFaqEO6qFaJkkfJ_BDkuyqbox0f-jGiRZUjXXEqeob6iP56PbP3dTSMs9XNC9f0K7aU0vF9b1kvuX_7z8)

Answer (score 0):

## [Raku](https://raku.org/), 51 bytes

```
1,2,3,{first 1==(*Xgcd$^x,$^y,$^z).all,($z..*)}...*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH7n1up4FCsYPvfUMdIx1inOi2zqLhEwdDWVkMrIj05RSWuQkclrhKIqzT1EnNydDRUqvT0tDRr9YDkf2uF4kSQ9ug4QwOD2P8A)
This is an expression for the infinite sequence of numbers.

- `1, 2, 3, { ... } ... *` is a lazy sequence starting with 1, 2, and 3, and with successive elements generated by the brace-delimited anonymous function.  The function mentions placeholder variables `$^x`, `$^y`, and `$^z`, so it takes the previous three elements of the sequence as arguments.
- `first 1 == (* Xgcd $^x, $^y, $^z).all, ($z .. *)` finds the first number in `$z .. *`--that is, the numbers starting from the last number in the sequence going up to infinity--such that the `gcd` of that number with each of the last three elements in the sequence is 1.